# problem in installing mendeleydesktop

Tags: mendeley

I recently download Mendeleydesktop for Linux from their site.
Exactly followed the installation proccess but the application wont start. When I run the program from terminal by typing:

Latitude-E6420:~$ `mendeleydesktop`

I get the following error report.

```
/usr/bin/../../opt/mendeleydesktop/bin/install-mendeley-link-handler.sh: 56: /usr/bin/../../opt/mendeleydesktop/bin/install-mendeley-link-handler.sh: cannot create /home/mbbn/.local/share/applications//mendeleydesktop.desktop: Permission denied
The databases in [/home/mbbn/.local/share/applications/] could not be updated.
/usr/share/themes/macOS Sierra/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:879: error: invalid string constant "panel", expected valid string constant
QIODevice::setTextModeEnabled (QFile, "/home/mbbn/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/log-2017-01-16.txt"): The device is not open
QIODevice::write (QFile, "/home/mbbn/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/log-2017-01-16.txt"): device not open
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
Error in finalize query "attempt to write a readonly database" : "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE"
[0117/012238:ERROR:nss_util.cc(94)] Failed to create /home/mbbn/.pki/nssdb directory.
Qt WebEngine Plugins directory not found. Trying fallback directory... Plugins as for example video codecs MAY NOT work.
[0117/012238:ERROR:nss_util.cc(94)] Failed to create /home/mbbn/.pki/nssdb directory.
Error in finalize query "attempt to write a readonly database" : "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE"
Error in open database "unable to open database file" : "/home/mbbn/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/www.mendeley.com/m.b.bagherieh@gmail.com-3848/search-index.sqlite"
Failed to open search index
Error in prepare query "unable to open database file" : "SELECT value FROM UpdateTokens WHERE key = :key"
Error in bind value "no statement prepared"
Error in execute query "query not prepared"
Error in step query "query not active"
Error in prepare query "unable to open database file" : "SELECT name, state FROM MonitoredFolders"
Error in step query "query not active"
Error in finalize query "attempt to write a readonly database" : "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE"
```

Please help me in finding the problem. Thanks

Comment: Did you try `sudo mendeleydesktop`?

Comment: Try with: sudo mendeleydesktop

Comment: Thanks @M.Becerra  . OK the program opened but this time I get the following  error: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
Qt WebEngine Plugins directory not found. Trying fallback directory... Plugins as for example video codecs MAY NOT work.
Unable to sort by field "LastReadField"
Unable to sort by field "LastReadField"

Comment: BTW do I have to start from sudo everytime? Why the icon does not work?

Comment: Actually it shouldn't need root privileges. The error message complains about not being able to open a database in the userspace. This suggests prior permissions issues (due to using sudo with graphical software, perhaps?).

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is related to [Mendeley won't start Ubuntu 16.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/q/916807/125111). For me, on Debian Stretch, this works:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```