# Mendeley won't start Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, mendeley

Im using Ubuntu 16.04.2 together with mendeley. When I want to start mendeley by clicking on the launcher icon, nothing happens. Launching `mendeleydesktop` via shell leads to:

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
```

The strange thing is, when I do `ps -e | grep mendel` the output shows two processes:

```
pid1    install-mendele <defunct>
pid2    mendeleydesktop
```

where `pid2 = pid1+1`. 
The first process most probably is

```
/opt/mendeleydesktop/bin/install-mendeley-link-handler.sh
```

When I kill both processes manually, mendeley starts again. Does anyone know, how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

There are some missing libraries, it seems. On Debian Stretch, I had to:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solved by just killing the remaining mendeleydesktop process.

```
pkill mendeleydesktop
```

Comment: Well I mentioned that in the OP.